# Interface Builder IB - Navigation Controller, skipping a view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

Hello I am new to iOS and have a question about navigating through my views.

I am using IB wiring up the PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons in the nav bar that pushes my views. This all works fine. However I am having trouble finding out where exactly what I need to do or where I need to place the code so I can skip over a view. To simplify my situation...

-I have 1 Nav Controller and 4 View Controllers named VC1, VC2, VC3, VC4. Each VC has a .H/.M
-Starting from VC1, they follow one after the other.

Say I want to skip VC3 and jump right to VC4 based on a setting in VC2. Where would I put the code to do this? Would I need to unhook the IBAction method from the NAV buttons at VC3?

I do apologize if this has been covered before. If there is a tut or if you know of a post that answers this, please let me know. I did do a search but the search was returning generic posts probably due to me using the wrong terminology.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some sample code that you wrote?
You talked about some settings, so settings means there might have some variables. To skip a view, you can check that variable and skip the VC3 pushing into navigation controller.

If you share your code, then it will be easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I really appreciate it. I'm not sure how to extract the source from the storyboard as I'm just CTRL- dragging from the "Next" button on the current view to the view controller of the next scene. I should have been more specific about the variable, it is actually just an on/off switch, so based on the switch, I would either go to VC3 or VC4. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm suggesting that while ctrl-dragging to make the "next" segue is generally the most elegant approach, when doing something that requires programmatic control (e.g. selectively choosing which view to go to), that you would make an `IBAction` instead (ctrl-drag to the .h file in the assistant editor and make an "action"). And you most definitely do _not_ want to use the ctrl-drag from the "previous" button to the previous scene. That's a disaster.

Comment: Rob, why would it be bad to use the drag and drop method going backwards? [This is not the way my views are implemented, I'm just curious.] I thought the nav controller managed all the views in memory. Come to think of it, I did find it strange that handling the "previous" button was different than going "next"

Comment: @user2013871 I wrote that before you clarified that you're using unwind segues to go back, in which case, you control-drag from the control to the exit outlet, you see your unwind outlet, and everything is good. But I've seen many people here on S.O. who, when first learning storyboards, use a push segue to go from VC1 to VC2, and then use a push segue to go from VC2 back to VC1, but in reality that ends up instantiating a second copy of VC1, which is the problem. But if you're using unwind segue to the exit outlet to go back to VC1 from VC2, then you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you want to push from VC2 to either VC3 or to VC4, rather than having VC3 immediately push to VC4 in special cases, I think it's better to just have VC2 push directly to the appropriate view controller. Thus you might have an `IBAction` in VC2 that would do this for you:

   ```
   - (IBAction)pushToNext:(id)sender
   {
       BOOL skipToVC4 = ... // put in whatever logic you'd use to bypass VC3 and go directly to VC4
       UIViewController *nextController;

       if (skipToVC4)
       {
           nextController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC4"];

           // obviously, if using NIBs, you'd do something like:
           // nextController = [[ViewController4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC4" bundle:nil];
       }
       else
       {
           nextController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];
       }

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
   }
   ```

   This way, when you pop back from VC4, you'll pop back directly to the appropriate view controller (e.g. if you pushed from VC2 to VC4, when you pop, you'll pop right back to VC2 automatically.

   And, obviously, if you're using storyboards, rather than manually invoking `pushViewController`, you could have two segues from VC2 (one to VC3 and one to VC4), give them appropriate identifiers, and then just invoke `performSegueWithIdentifier` to segue to the appropriate view controller. But the idea is the same: You can define an `IBAction` that performs the appropriate segue depending upon whatever logic you so choose.
2. You say that you have "PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons in the nav bar that pushes my views", I wonder about your "PREVIOUS" button. Is that doing a `popViewControllerAnimated`? Generally, a "NEXT" button will push to a new view controller, but the "PREVIOUS" button should not push to the previous view, but pop back to it. If you don't pop back, you can end up with multiple instances of some of your prior view controllers. Thus, the "PREVIOUS" button should be linked to an `IBOutlet` that does something like:

   ```
   - (IBAction)popToPrevious:(id)sender
   {
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
   ```
3. When popping back, you'll obviously pop back to the view controller that you pushed from. If you want to skip a few of the view controllers as you're popping back in iOS versions prior to 6.0, you would use `popToViewController` or `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`. For example, let's say that you pushed from VC1 to VC2, to VC3, to VC4. If you want to pop back from VC4 all the way to VC1, you would hook up and `IBAction` in VC4 like:

   ```
   - (IBAction)popToRoot:(id)sender
   {
       [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
   ```

   Or, if you wanted to pop back from VC4 to VC2, you would

   ```
   - (IBAction)popToVC2:(id)sender
   {
       for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
       {
           if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]])
           {
               [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
               return;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   You can avoid this iteration through the `navigationController.viewControllers` if you passed a reference of VC2 to VC3 and then again to VC4, but sometimes the above technique is easier.

   By the way, if you're supporting iOS 6 and above, only, and are using storyboards, you can also use unwind segues, which are a more elegant way of popping back to a particular view controller. But it's not clear whether (a) you're using storyboards; and (b) you're supporting iOS 6 and above only, so I'll refrain from a discussion of unwind segues at this point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! This really helps and not only answered my question but you also provided thinking points for going "previous".

Comment: (continued)...I am using Interface Builder (storyboards) and I am targeting ios6. I am using "unwindto..." to handle my "previous" button action. Thank you so much for your detailed reply. This is really helpful and makes things more clear on how navigating through forms work.

Comment: @user2013871 - Ah, unwind segue is the perfect way to do it. I think I read too much into your comment about "pushing" back to the previous controller. You're unwinding back, which is perfect!

Comment: No, that was me. I'm not familiar with the terminology yet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First:
**Show us some code, where you are pushing new view controllers, maybe your whole navigation controller code**

Second **(Solution)**:

I assume:

- Your prev/next buttons are linked to your navigationController class
- you have the appropriate methods (prevPressed:/nextPressed:), which are called, when you click one of the buttons

**I can help you with the following:**

- you know which controller is visible at the moment with the `visibleViewController` @property
- each time you click on a button in the navBar you can ask the `visibleViewController` which next/previous view controller should be pushed/popped

Best solution would be, if all of your controllers VC1/2/3/4 are a subclass of a viewController class, which defines a method in it's interface:

```
- (Class)nextViewControllerClass;
- (Class)previousViewControllerClass;
```

and in the implementation:

```
- (Class)nextViewControllerClass {
    return [VC4 class];
}

- (Class)previousViewControllerClass {
    return [VC1 class];
}
```

And in your navigationController code the do this:

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *nextViewController = [[[self.visibleViewController nextViewControllerClass] alloc] init];
    [self pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. This is great stuff. I did see this this approach used in a book to set the look and feel of the views. I suspect at some point, I will do this but right now, I'm at the point where I'm still trying to get my head around how everything works. Thanks again for taking the time to reply to my post. I really appreciate it.